# Can Rutherford model (1911) be "saved" if the orbiting electron in the atom is divided into sub-particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, history

The well-known contradiction of the Rutherford atom model (1911, a planetary atom model) is that the electrons rotating around the nucleus will be emitting the electromagnetic waves, thus losing energy, slowing their rotation, and eventually falling onto the nucleus within a very short time (picoseconds?). This contradiction was somewhat overcome by the postulates of the Bohr atom model, which eventually became one of the models leading to quantum mechanics (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model#Origin ).

**Can (or could?) the Rutherford model be saved by staying within the classical mechanics and classical electrodynamics, and ensuring the stability of the atoms by allowing the electrons to be divided into sub-particles, which rotate around the nucleus in such a way that no electromagnetic waves are emitted?** Bonus points if the stable configurations based on such sub-division of electron into sub-particles are somehow discrete and can explain the Rydberg formula.

E.g., for an atom of hydrogen, the electron can be split into two identical sub-particles rotating around the nucleus along the same circular orbit, always staying on the opposite ends of the diameter of this orbit. Such two half-electrons and the nucleus can be balanced by rotation, and the first electrical dipole moment of the system will be identically zero. The higher-order dipole moments will(?) still be non-zero and will(?) change in time, so such system will(?) still be emitting electromagnetic waves, but as a higher-order and hopefully weaker effect. If one divides the electron into a larger number of sub-particles, can one obtain the stable, non-EM emitting, model of the atom, within classical mechanics and classical electrodynamics?

Were such models considered in Rutherford's and Bohr's times? If they were, why were they rejected - available experimental evidence that the electron is not sub-divided into sub-particles inside the atom? impossibility to completely get rid of EM emission by dividing the electron into sub-particles? anything else?

Comment: Electric dipole is a system of pair of opposing charges of same magnitude. So your "half-electrons" model technically is not a dipole. Second - such "dipole" electromagnetic field would be distorted in the middle by proton(s) strong EM field in the nucleus, so it's highly questionable if such dipole could exist with distorting field at center at all. And finally, such rotating dipole should be equivalent to oscillating dipole model, hence it should emit EM waves and loose dipole moment over time and collapse to the center of nuclei, according to classic electrodynamics. So it's same problem.

Comment: Agnius, thank you for your comments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Agnius: My question does not call the "half-electron" model a dipole, it says that its first dipole moment is going to be identical zero. Dipole moment applies and can be calculated for an arbitrary distribution of charges, not just for a dipole of two equal charges of opposite signs. You also wrote "such rotating dipole should be equivalent to oscillating dipole model, hence it should emit EM waves and loose dipole moment over time". Such system will have zero dipole moment, and it will not emit EM radiation (at least as the 1st order effect).

Comment: Agnius: not sure what you meant by ""such "dipole" electromagnetic field would be distorted in the middle by proton(s) strong EM field in the nucleus". When I was writing about the dipole moment in a hypothetical hydrogen atom, I meant the dipole moment of the entire hydrogen atom, consisting of two half-electrons and the proton at the center. It is zero.

Comment: @Agnius: For such hypothetical atom, two half-electrons are at the distance of R from the proton. The Coulomb force acting on each half-electron and directed towards the proton is $F=Ke^2((1/2)/(R^2)−(1/4)/(2R)^2)=7Ke^2/(16R^2)$. The 2nd Newton law of motion for the half-electron rotating around the circular orbit is $m \omega^2R=F$, where $m$ is the mass of the half(!)-electron and $\omega$ is angular speed of its rotation, giving the relation between the R and $\omega$ allowing to balance this system.

Comment: Sure, your atom model has zero dipole moment as per $\mu = \sum_i q_i \vec d_i $. That's why complete atom is neutral. But then it's not wise to model emission as total dipole moment, because EM waves are emitted not by whole atom, but by exact electron/ exact dipole. In your case EM would be emitted by 1 or 2-ond "half-electron", decreasing it's dipole moment in the process.

Comment: Agnius: indeed, the proton at the nucleus generates the constant electric field, and one may prefer to consider the EM emission of just two half-electrons (rotating along the circular orbit and staying at the opposite ends of its certain diameter) in such hypothetical hydrogen atom.  One can see that the dipole moment of such pair of rotating half-electrons is constant (as follows from the formula for a dipole moment of point charges that you provided). Therefore, this pair of half-electrons will not be emitting EM waves (to the first order).

Comment: Aginus:  The dipole moment of two half-electrons rotating around the center of the atom along the same circular trajectory, staying at the opposite ends of its diameter: ${\boldsymbol \mu} = 0.5 e {\bf r}_1 + 0.5 e {\bf r}_2 = 0.5({\bf r}_1 + {\bf r}_2) e$. Note that $0.5({\bf r}_1 + {\bf r}_2) = const$ because it is the center of the atom, which is at rest.